# Telerik RadEditor spellchecker is not working

Tags: telerik, spell-checking, radeditor

Trying to implement spellcheck and I got a message:

> Web.config registration missing. The Telerik dialogs require a
>   HTTPHandler registration in the web.config file. Please use the
>   control's smart tag to add the handler automatically.

I did it by adding but still have the same message is coming up... I need some help please!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Spell Check Handler Server Error, AjaxUrl property is used to set the path to the handler and is used in scenarios where you may have a UrlRewriter module which overwrites the handlers url even if they are set in the web.config. A correct value of this property is like follows:
RadEditor1.SpellCheckSettings.AjaxUrl = "Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.aspx";

Once you set the new AjaxUrl value, go to the web.config file and update the Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd instances to Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.aspx

Check these articles for more information about problems with handlers: https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/details/error-web-config-registration-missing!-the-telerik-dialogs-require-a-httphandler-registration-in-the-web-config-file-
and 
https://www.telerik.com/forums/radspell-javascript-error